# Image uploading doesn't work on webview

Tags: php, webview

I have website with option to upload picture, and when i open that website with browser it works on desktop and mobile, but i made android app that open link of that website in WebView and when i try to choose image to upload it doesn't open any folder or gallery to choose image for upload.
Can you help me how can i make this to work on WebView if it's possible?

Here is my html and PHP code for that part of uploading image, and in database I only save path to the image which is uploaded in folder on server:

php

```
$filename=$_FILES['file']['name'];
$filetype=$_FILES['file']['type'];
if($filetype=='image/jpeg' or $filetype=='image/png' or $filetype=='image/gif'){
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'img/'.$filename);
    $filepath="img/".$filename;

    $sql="insert into tbl_cars values(0,'$maker','$model','$year','$price','$power','$speed','$color','$fuel','$filepath')";
    $query=mysql_query($sql);       
}
```

html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Image:</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input class="form-control" type="file" name="file">
    </div>
</div>
```